# R add an inhomogeneous element to vector and make it a list

Tags: r, data.table

I have a vector

```
row = c(Estimate = 1, pvalue = 0.5)
```

How can I make a list like below with the vector `row`?

```
list(name = "class2", Estimate = 1, pvalue = 0.5)
```

---

Background:

I'm constructing a data.table row by row

```
dt = data.table()
dt = rbind(dt, list(name = "class1", Estimate = 0.5, pvalue = 0.7))
```

Now I calculated another row, starting as a vector from say `lm`

```
row = c(Estimate = 1, pvalue = 0.5)
```

I want to append it to `dt`.

How can I make a list like below with `row`

```
list(name = "class2", Estimate = 1, pvalue = 0.5)
```

(NB `name` is character and other columns are numeric)

btw, is there a better way to construct the data.table?

Comment: Your question is unclear. However, growing an object like that is the least efficient approach you can use in R (or any programming language).

Comment: @Roland I made an edit to make my question clear, thanks

Comment: @Roland, efficiency isn't just a memory/cpu issue, if my table is less than 1000 rows, then the most efficient approach is the one that I can code in least time. Also, for data.table (not data.frame), this seems to be less problematic

Comment: Bad practice is bad practice. You probably know in advance how many rows you'll need so if you don't want to learn writing really efficient code, you could at least pre-allocate, which is not more difficult than what you are doing now. The data.table developers feel a shiver each time someone uses their package, which is written for maximum performance, with code that inefficient. Finally, you are mistaken when you think this is less problematic with a data.table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.list` would do the job :

```
row = c(Estimate = 1, pvalue = 0.5)  
c(as.list(row), name = "class2") 
# $Estimate
# [1] 1
# 
# $pvalue
# [1] 0.5
# 
# $name
# [1] "class2"
```